# What is the use of the const keyword when assigning structure values?

Tags: c, constants, structure

What is the use of `const` keyword in this program?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct x{
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    struct x xx;
    xx = (const struct x) {0};
    xx.a = 10;
    printf("%d, %d", xx.a, xx.b);
}
```

There is no difference in output when I run without `const` keyword. What is its significance here?

Comment: `const` has no significant meaning here. It's like writing `(const int)42` which is pretty useless.

Comment: While it's a good start to compile, link and run such a little experiment, it will not give a final answer. You need to consult the standard. What do you find there?

Comment: "There is no difference in output when I run without const keyword." Correct. That's the whole point of a (compile-time) type qualifier: _if_ it compiles, then there should be no runtime difference (apart from potential UB and compiler optimizations).

Comment: Some very bad embedded systems compiler might decide to place compound literals in RAM instead of read-only flash. That's about the only valid reason to type `const` there - suppose for example that the compound literal is placed in .bss and copied into the stack variable from there.

Comment: More likely though, some confused people like to spam `const` all over the place, like declaring local function parameters `const` even though they were copied by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what is it's significance here?

None.

When you assign to `xx` like `xx = something;` you need that `something` to have the basic type `struct x`. That happens due to the cast. So if you do

```
(struct x) {0};
```

an anonymous object of type `struct x` will be created and it can be assigned to `xx` like:

```
xx = (struct x) {0};
```

Now adding a const qualifier in the cast means that the anonymous object is a constant. However, it doesn't really matter that it's constant as you don't write to it anyway. The only operation performed on the anonymous object is the read operation performed during the assignment to `xx`. For an assignment it makes no difference whether the source object (RHS object) is a constant or not.

So: No, for your code `const` has no significance.

**Can we construct code where it matters?**

Yes, consider this (obfuscated useless) code:

```
int y;
y = ++(struct x) {0, 42}.b;
printf("%d\n", y);
```

It will create an anonymous object with values `.a=0` and `.b=42` and then increment and return `.b`. In other words, it will print 43.

If you add `const` to the cast, you'll get a compiler error like:

```
main.cpp:26:9: error: increment of member 'b' in read-only object
   26 |     y = ++(const struct x) {0, 42}.b;
      |         ^~
```

So here the `const` keyword did matter.

Comment: It's not a cast, it's a compound literal. C doesn't have anonymous structs other than as an unnamed member of another struct/union.

Answer (score 1):

C 2018 6.3.2.1 2 says qualifiers such `const` are removed when any object is used for its value in an expression:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the unary `&` operator, the `++` operator, the `--` operator, or the left operand of the `.` operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called *lvalue conversion*. **If the lvalue has qualified type, the value has the unqualified version of the type of the lvalue**; additionally, if the lvalue has atomic type, the value has the non-atomic version of the type of the lvalue; otherwise, the value has the type of the lvalue.

Thus, in `xx = (const struct x) {0};`, `(const struct x) {0};` is a compound literal that creates a `const struct x` object. However, in taking the value of this object, `const` is removed, and the result is a `struct x` value. (The “value” of a structure is the aggregate of the values of all its members.)

Thus, in this use, the `const` ultimately has no effect. However, the compound literal does create a `const` object. The effect of this could be seen in other uses. For example, with `const struct x *p = & (const struct x) {0};`, we take the address of the compound structure. Then if we attempt to remove `const` and modify the structure, as with `((struct x *) p)->a = 3;`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. The compiler could have placed the structure in read-only memory, and attempting to modify it could generate a trap. Or, during optimization, the compiler could have used the fact that the structure is `const` to ignore any possibility it could change. For example, in:

```
const struct *p = & (const struct x) {0};
((struct x *) p)->a = 3;
printf("%d\n", p->a);
```

the program might print “0” because in the `p->a` in the `printf`, the compiler uses the fact that `p->a` is defined to be a `const` zero.

Answer (score 0):

This will zero-initialize a temporary `struct x`:

```
xx = (const struct x) {0};
```

and that temporary will then be used to copy assign `xx`. That's what it will do no matter if the temporary object is `const` or not.

---

An example with a popular compiler (gcc) shows that it'll simply zero out the two members in `xx`, in both the `const` and non-`const` case without actually creating a temporary object. The compiled program acts *as-if* it did though:

```
xor     edx, edx
xor     esi, esi
```